# Node Script fails to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a fairly straightforward node script. It pulls in data from an API, loops through it all and compiles 2 reports. One in a JSON format, the other in CSV. It then, sorts the data and finally exports both a JSON file and then 2 CSV files (duplicates).

I have put logging into my script and found that the script fails to advance up to and past the part where I sort the arrays before exporting them into file formats.

What could be causing this?

** It's worth noting that if I remove the sorting and exporting at the bottom for either the JSON or the CSV, the script will run completely. It just wont do both at the same time. But stranger still is that it was working last week in this exact same configuration, but suddenly breaks.

```
const { xm, xm_env, uncaught_endpoint, prod_xm } = require('./../config');
const util           = require('./../node_modules/xmtoolbox/lib/util');
const path           = require('path');
const workflow       = process.argv.slice(2);
const fs             = require('fs')
const pathname       = './../../../Logs/';
const filename       = path.basename(__filename, '.js');

let fields = [
  'sub_name',
  'sub_uuid',
  'sub_form_name',
  'sub_form_uuid',
  'workflow_name',
  'workflow_uuid',
  'owner_targetName',
  'owner_uuid',
  'owner_firstName',
  'owner_lastName',
  'recipient_targetName',
  'recipient_uuid',
  'recipient_firstName',
  'recipient_lastName',
];

(async (env, workflow) => {
  try {
    const report        = [];
    const json          = [];
    const subscriptions = await xm.subscriptions.getMany(env);

    util.buildLogger(pathname, filename).info('Pulled in all the subscriptions...');

    await Promise.all(subscriptions.map(async sub => {
      if (sub.criteria) {
        let sub_obj = {
          sub_name         : sub.name,
          sub_uuid         : sub.id,
          sub_form_name    : sub.form.name,
          sub_form_uuid    : sub.form.id,
          workflow_name    : sub.form.plan.name,
          workflow_uuid    : sub.form.plan.id,
          owner_targetName : sub.owner.targetName,
          owner_uuid       : sub.owner.id,
          owner_firstName  : sub.owner.firstName,
          owner_lastName   : sub.owner.lastName
        };

        let json_obj = {
          recipients        : [],
          id                : sub.id,
          name              : sub.name,
          form              : sub.form,
          owner             : sub.owner,
          created           : sub.created,
          criteria          : sub.criteria.data,
          description       : sub.description,
          notificationDelay : sub.notificationDelay
        };

        report.push(sub_obj);

        if (sub.recipients && sub.recipients.count > 1) {
          let recipients = await xm.subscriptions.getSubscribers(env, '', sub.id);

          await Promise.all(recipients.map(async r => {
            json_obj.recipients.push({ targetName: r.targetName, id : r.id })
            let recip_obj = {
              sub_name             : sub.name,
              sub_uuid             : sub.id,
              sub_form_name        : sub.form.name,
              sub_form_uuid        : sub.form.id,
              workflow_name        : sub.form.plan.name,
              workflow_uuid        : sub.form.plan.id,
              owner_targetName     : sub.owner.targetName,
              owner_uuid           : sub.owner.id,
              owner_firstName      : sub.owner.firstName,
              owner_lastName       : sub.owner.lastName,
              recipient_targetName : r.targetName,
              recipient_firstName  : r.firstName,
              recipient_lastName   : r.lastName,
              recipient_uuid       : r.id
            };
        }

        json.push(json_obj);
      }
    }));

    util.buildLogger(pathname, filename).info('Looped through all subscriptions and built report arrays...');



    // --------------    LOGGING NEVER MAKES IT PAST THIS PART  ---------------------- //



    let sorted_report = await util.awaitSort(report, ['form_name', 'sub_name']);

    util.buildLogger(pathname, filename).info('Built Sorted Report...');

    let sorted_json   = await util.awaitSort(json, ['name']);

    util.buildLogger(pathname, filename).info('Built sorted_json Report...');

    fs.writeFileSync('./../../../Feeds/Subs_JSON.json', JSON.stringify(sorted_json))
    util.buildCSV(fields, sorted_report, 'Subscriptions');
    util.buildCSV(fields, sorted_report, `${util.today()}_Subscriptions`, true);

    util.buildLogger(pathname, filename).info('All files written...');
  } catch (e) {
    util.uncaught_exception_webhook(xm_env, path.basename(__filename), workflow, uncaught_endpoint, e);
  }
})(prod_xm, workflow);
```

Await Sort Function from UTIL file

```
async function awaitSort(data, keys) {
  let sorted_data = data.sort((a, b) => {
    keys.map(i => {
      if (a[i].toLowerCase() < b[i].toLowerCase()) {
        return -1
      }

      if (a[i].toLowerCase > b[i].toLowerCase()) {
        return 1;
      }

      return 0;
    });
  });

  return sorted_data;
}
```

Comment: `subscriptions.map` does not return Promises. So, `await Promise.all(subscriptions.map` can't resolve. You should simply do `for( let sub of subscriptions){ ... `

Comment: Please, send the util.awaitSort codes

Comment: ... actually, none of your `.map()` returns any Promise. Buy you `await Promise.all()` them. Why? Of course the `Promise.all()` will never resolve if the array you pass it contains no Promise.

Comment: Ok, but what about like I said if I remove the content in the script which relates to the JSON (json, json_obj, json_obj.recipients.push etc...) If I remove those references, the script works perfect. It's when I add this other JSON thing that it breaks. 

Maybe I'm not using Promises correctly, I have it like this so that I can process large volumes of data without jumping to the next part of the script before it finishes. It's been working for me fine so far...

Comment: I've added the sort function code, @JeremyThille

Comment: Your sort method is wrong totally. What happens if a[i] === undefined?
Just use this [...].sort( (x,y) => x.field1 < y.field2 ? -1 : 1)
It doesn't make any sense if both are equal

Comment: Why your sort method is async while there is no await action?

Comment: Not sure, I don't think I am using it properly. The way I was using it in my mind was, add AWAIT or ASYNC or PROMISE.ALL to prevent the rest of the code from running until this section of the code is completed. Doing this, in my mind prevents let's say FUNCTION B (which processes the result of FUNCTION A) from running before FUNCTION A is complete and returned a valid object to process. I'm assuming in wildly wrong in this regard?

Comment: You are using `await Promise.all` on things that are not Promises. This code just can't work. If you want to wait for everything before continuing, simply use `for( let subscription of subscriptions) { await stuff(); }` job done